# How to put an image for the bottom of the page

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to put an image for the bottom of my page. i tried to put it by using android:gravity="bottom" but, my image did not align to the bottom of the page.

Here is my XML,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_land_layout_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/code"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="textPassword" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/name"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_land_margin_both"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_land_margin_both"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_Land_margin_top"
                    android:background="#0f4b9b"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:textColor="@color/LoginButtonColor" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poweredBy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/poweredby"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"

            />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the view of my image.

[image]

I need to add the powered by image for the bottom of the page.

Comment: On your ScrollView change height to fill parent android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: simple use align parent bottom in your layout in which u have placed the imageview...u can use it directly in imageview too..by removing the linear layout

Comment: yup like Neha said you can use align parent bottom, i think it is more easy to you use RelativeLayout if you just make a layout with login page inside

Comment: Neha , Removed the linear layout.and used android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed the imageview widget inside the Linearlayout. Please remove the Linearlayout and only use the ImageView Widget. Use the following code for placing the imageview at the bottom of the screen.

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/poweredby"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: Added android:fillViewport="true" for scroll view. Now working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

your code is right so dont worry about it.
Just add one line to your scrollView.

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

thats it, you will get result you want

Comment: Wow! What a quick answer . Thank you so much. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Relative layout** that fills the whole screen you should be able to use [android:layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3Alayout_alignParentBottom) to move the Image to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use that linear layout remove that

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poweredBy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/poweredby"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:scaleType="center"

            />
```

To your scrollview add this `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: removed the linear layout. Problem is still there.

Comment: Added android:fillViewport="true" for scroll view. Now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things.

1.) Make a Linear Layout and set on of the properties of your ImageView as

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/LogInButton"
```

and set some padding on top in this LinearLayout which is holding this image.

2.) Use footer

[image]

See this tutorial on how to set footer

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example.html

Comment: Added android:fillViewport="true" for scroll view. Now working as expected.